# Exchanging azure AD token with Identity server token

Tags: flutter, authentication, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have a architecture consisted of mobile application(flutter), api 1, and api 2. The api 2 is secured by identity server 4. My scenario is mobile application need to authenticate user via azure ad directory. After getting the azure ad token in mobile application, i have no idea how to exchange it with identity server 4 token that is currently used to secure my api 2. My current workaround implementation is done by using flutter appauth to open up the identity server 4 login screen which will redirect user to azure ad login. Once user login, the identity server 4 will return the access token that can be used to access api 2 to my mobile application. In general, my mobile application will pass the token to api 1 and api 1 to api 2 during request. Just wonder is this architecture has any issue? Because recently i came across the Extension grant in identity server 4 from link http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html. Which technically i should get azure ad token via flutter appauth and pass it to api 1 and then api 1 exchange it with api 2 to get the access token which is shown in the extension grant documentation above. May i know should i change my current existing workaround architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your mobile applications and API's and web app to all use IdentityServer. And then login to AzureAD through IdentityServer.

Like this picture tries to show:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Yup, currently i  let my mobile open up browser which it will use identity server login where we prompt user azure ad login page to let user login.

Comment: What I mean is that its easier to let the user authenticate to Azure AD through IdentityServer, so that AzureAD issues a token to IdentityServer and your clients/mobile only trusts IdentityServer and are not aware of AzureAD

Comment: Ya, you are right. Sorry my sentence did not express what I trying to say correctly.

Comment: So, what it your question? or should I clarify something?

Comment: I wonder if I were to implement the delegation grant method, how do my identity server validate an access token that is not issue by itself?

Comment: For new development, you should try to aim for what OAuth2.1 recommends and that is to only use the authorization code flow or client credentials flow, all the other flows are more or less deprecated. With my picture, IdentityServer issues its own authorization flow with AzureAD, so between them they have their own set of tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation and advice, i will convince the team about my implementation. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think the delegation grant is for something else entirely @LowChenThye, like when one API has access to scope1, the token for which gets passed to API2, which has access to scope2 - the API2 can use the delegation grant to request scope2 be added to the token, based on the token it received from API1